# Ext.Element.scrollIntoView seems not to work for a flex-ed component of a vbox layout

Tags: extjs4.1

ExtJS 4.1.1.

I have a panel with `layout: { type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch' }`. Inside it is a container with layout of `{type: 'anchor', anchor: '100% 100%'}` and `flex: 3`. Inside the container is a plain panel (containing HTML) with `autoScroll: true`.

Scrolling from the UI works fine. However, a call to `scrollIntoView` passing in the Element for the div that results has no effect.

I note that the div does has overflow-x/y: auto. However, it has a height attribute of a giant number (2241px), which I suspect is at the root of this issue.

What's going on?